# is it possible to covert json string in php?

Tags: php, json

Is it possible to decode this by json_decode method?

```
[{"sample1":{"t":"{a={b=1},c={d=2}}"}, "sample2" : "something"}]
```

I'm getting NULL while decoding {a={b=1},c={d=2}}.

Anyone help me?

Comment: `a={b=1},c={d=2}}` is not JSON.

Comment: FYI:  json_decode(ABOVE_FULL_INPUT) parsed as JSON ARRAY successfully.

Comment: Then what more do you need, resp. what is your actual question here?

Comment: json_decode (

[{ "sample1" : { "t" : " { "a" : { "b" : 1 }, "c" : { "d" : 2 }}"}, "sample2" : "something"}]

, true); returning NULL. @CBroe

Comment: That is not valid JSON, so it makes no sense to try and decode it as such.

Comment: Could you please let me the valid json for this ? @CBroe

Comment: No, I can not, because we don’t know what “this” actually is or is supposed to be. It makes little sense that you ask us to fix faulty JSON. This needs to be fixed at the place where you get this data from.

Comment: please check this link phpfiddle.org/main/code/m5r7-2g0f

Answer (score 4):

There is `json_decode` and `json_encode`, but your string is not valid JSON. It should be `[{"sample1":{"t":"{"a":{"b":1},"c":{"d":2}}"}, "sample2" : "something"}]`

Comment: I had tried that. But, while decoding following as JSON Array

[{"sample1":{"t":"{"a":{"b":1},"c":{"d":2}}"}, "sample2" : "something"}]

json_decode method returns NULL.

Comment: @GokulaKannan you have't tried it good than.People here give you hints they don't write your code.

Comment: And your json is also invalid,what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Arslan.H I don't know how to host and share on online. 

Just try this code in any online php editor.

`<?php
echo "test";
echo var_dump(json_decode('[{"sample1":{"t":"{a={b=1},c={d=2}}"}, "sample2" : "something"}]', true));
echo "<br><br>";
echo var_dump(json_decode('[{"sample1":{"t":"{"a":{"b":1},"c":{"d":2}}"}, "sample2" : "something"}]', true));
?>
`

Comment: JSON as value a of another JSON. @Arslan.H

Comment: Can you explain me what is this:{a={b=1},c={d=2}}?

Comment: Describe whats your goal here?For the whole project?

Comment: I had tried to ask is it possible to json parse that kind a data. @Arslan.H

Comment: unable to parse json inside a json string. @Arslan.H

Comment: Why do you need this {a={b=1},c={d=2}} it makes no sense.And it can't be decoded since it's not JSON.You could use dome regex paterns to decode it but i don't see the point of it.

Comment: It's failing becouse {a={b=1},c={d=2}} is not json

Comment: `"{"a":{"b":1},"c":{"d":2}}"` Its also failing. Correct format is {"a":{"b":1},"c":{"d":2}}. Then I have to do some regex checks to remove that quotes?

NOTE: the quotes before open braces removed. @Arslan.H

Comment: I can't i wanted to help you out with this but i have no nerves since you are not listening.

Comment: @Arslan.H please check this link 

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m5r7-2g0f